# iOS - Does the constraint reference items in different view hierarchies? That's illegal

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios-autolayout

I have made different layouts for iPhone and iPad using `class sizes` (I have left `Any-Any` layout blank). Layouts for iPhone including `Regular-Compact` are working fine but I am getting issue is layouts of iPad.

I have made `Regular-Any` layout for iPad Landscape, and `Any-Regular` for iPad Portrait.

I am using two `IBOutletCollections` for both landscape and portrait constraints and apply them as,

```
if (_needsiPadConstraintsApplied) {      
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation)) {
            [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:self.iPadLandscapeConstraints];
            [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:self.iPadPortraitConstraints];           
        } else {
            [NSLayoutConstraint deactivateConstraints:self.portraitConstraintsIPad];
            [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:self.landscapeConstraintsIPad];
        }
        _needsiPadConstraintsApplied = NO;
    }
```

But my app is terminating when I run my project using iPad,

**Error:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with items > and
>   <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7f9a1b62a9e0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES;
>   layer = > because they have no common ancestor. Does the constraint
>   reference items in different view hierarchies? That's illegal.'

I have tried a lot solutions but all are not working for me.

Comment: I think you may be accessing or modifying the constraint of other size class when you run your app on iPad, make sure you are accessing correct IBOutlet constraint of correct size class.

Comment: for landscape mode only constraints of `Regular-Any` are attached with `landscapeConstraintsIPad` but error occurs when I activate constraints programatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily set landscape an portrait mode by using size classes without any codes for all orientations.
just a look for the [Video link](http://codewithchris.com/8-completing-the-ui-with-auto-layout-and-size-classes/) .

and also these .

- [link 1](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113768/adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-getting-started)
- [link 2](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Using_Size_Classes_to_Design_Universal_iOS_User_Interfaces)

thank you.

Comment: I have different layouts for iPad (portrait and landscape). My `Any-Any` layout is empty and I have `Regular-Any` and `Any-Regular` for both landscape and portrait view of iPad respectively.

Comment: you mean Regular hight and Regular width.?